# Nested comments in comments

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, mongoose, nested-lists

```
 const post =   {
        "comments": [
            {
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "comments": [
                            {
                                "comments": [
                                    {
                                        "comments": [],
                                        "_id": "60d6ab9207c0a573786a9e65",
                                        "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                                        "content": "good post 3",
                                        "createdAt": "2021-06-26T04:22:42.337Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T04:22:42.337Z",
                                        "__v": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "_id": "60d6962cee10aa73f820b974",
                                "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                                "content": "good post 2",
                                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T02:51:24.111Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T04:22:42.622Z",
                                "__v": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "comments": [],
                                "_id": "60d705784ab01c354cf7f445",
                                "userId": "60c15ac41ed8da1ab4efe7f3",
                                "content": "Comment deleted by User",
                                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T10:46:16.813Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T12:29:06.398Z",
                                "__v": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "comments": [],
                                "_id": "60d706febcba957b04406547",
                                "userId": "60c15ac41ed8da1ab4efe7f3",
                                "content": "yes it is a good post 1 from alexane Updated",
                                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T10:52:46.679Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T12:17:58.879Z",
                                "__v": 0
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "60d695b4ee10aa73f820b973",
                        "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                        "content": "good post 1",
                        "createdAt": "2021-06-26T02:49:24.426Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T12:30:44.872Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "60d68e32dff84439a4d3b191",
                "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                "content": "good post",
                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T02:17:22.625Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T02:49:24.820Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "comments": [],
                        "_id": "60d6c2d917d0b12be44742d2",
                        "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                        "content": "nice post 1",
                        "createdAt": "2021-06-26T06:02:01.420Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T06:02:01.420Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "60d6bebf17d0b12be44742d1",
                "userId": "60c418582f7066090ced4a51",
                "content": "nice post",
                "createdAt": "2021-06-26T05:44:31.436Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T06:02:01.676Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have a deep nested object which I got from mongoose.

a. How do I iterate through this deep nested objects? Should  I use a recursion and loop because I can't seem to wrap my head around this? I manage to iterate through to the end of the comments . I managed to come up with something as brute force as below but i am kinda stuck here.

```
const findObject = (obj) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.comments.length; i++) {
        const element = obj.comments[i];
        for (let y = 0; y < element.comments.length; y++) {
            const newElements = element.comments[y];
            for (let z = 0; z < newElements.comments.length; z++) {
                const newElementsZ = newElements.comments[z];
                console.log(newElementsZ)

            }
        }
    }
};
```

b. How to calculate the total number of comments, in this case it is 8 comments ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use recursion, or if it's deep and cause problem, use queue/stack to emulate real recursion calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to do it. (since it has indefinite number of layers, write all the nested loops doesn't really scale).

```js
const post = { "comments": [{ "comments": [{ "comments": [{ "comments": [{ "comments": [], "_id": "60d6ab9207c0a573786a9e65", }], "_id": "60d6962cee10aa73f820b974", }, { "comments": [], "_id": "60d705784ab01c354cf7f445", }, { "comments": [], "_id": "60d706febcba957b04406547", } ], "_id": "60d695b4ee10aa73f820b973", }], "_id": "60d68e32dff84439a4d3b191", }, { "comments": [{ "comments": [], "_id": "60d6c2d917d0b12be44742d2", }], "_id": "60d6bebf17d0b12be44742d1", } ] }

function CountComment(data){
  let count = 0
  for(let c of data.comments){
    ++count
    count+=CountComment(c)
  }
  return count
}

console.log(CountComment(post))
```

---

Or you can use stack/queue based approach if the recursion depth cause problem.

```js
const post = { "comments": [{ "comments": [{ "comments": [{ "comments": [{ "comments": [], "_id": "60d6ab9207c0a573786a9e65", }], "_id": "60d6962cee10aa73f820b974", }, { "comments": [], "_id": "60d705784ab01c354cf7f445", }, { "comments": [], "_id": "60d706febcba957b04406547", } ], "_id": "60d695b4ee10aa73f820b973", }], "_id": "60d68e32dff84439a4d3b191", }, { "comments": [{ "comments": [], "_id": "60d6c2d917d0b12be44742d2", }], "_id": "60d6bebf17d0b12be44742d1", } ] }

function CountComment(post){
  let nodes = [post]
  let count = 0
  while(nodes.length){
    let node = nodes.pop()
    ++count
    for(let c of node.comments)
       nodes.push(c)
  }
  return count-1 //remove post itself
}

console.log(CountComment(post))
```

Comment: btw here is one-liner `function CountComment(data){ return post.comments.reduce((a,c)=>a+CountComment(c)+1,0)}` (I do **not** suggest using this)

Comment: thank you very much ,  so it is best to use to a stack or queue for this kind of depth object traversal

Comment: @desh it depends, if normal recursion works well (i.e. when you know the max depth would not be too large), it has the benefit for being cleaner.

Comment: I don't think I would know the max depth , wouldn't u think a tree would be a better data structure for this ?

Comment: @desh well your current input structure (`const post`) **is** a tree (with children named as `comments`), not really sure what you're saying.

Comment: Thank you, you kinda answered the question.  I wasn't sure whether this post and comments is actually a tree data structure but now I know It is . I think I will work from there. I kinda need to brush up on my data structure :)

Comment: @desh oh I just realize you're comparing (stack vs queue), not (stack-or-queue vs recursion). ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68143147/nested-comments-in-comments/68143280?noredirect=1#comment120443440_68143280))

Comment: @desh I use stack simply because javascript doesn't have efficient (simple) way to implement queue.

Comment: @desh stack would be Depth-First-Search while Queue would be Breadth-First-Search. which is not that relevant to count node anyway. (btw, normal recursion call is DFS) (I ***guess*** DFS would usually have less node queued for usual post)

Comment: I kinda forgot all of the ds and searching. Need to brush up on this hahaha but thanks though for your help.  :)